# Event must be of delegate type?

Tags: c#

Not very familiar with declaring and using events and received error,

> Event must be of delegate type

Basically want to pass `IMyInterface` as a dependency to another class where that class can subscribe to receive `MyClassEvent` events and the event data is `MyClass`.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
   event MyClass MyClassEvent;
}

public class Implementation: IMyInterface
{
     event MyClass MyClassEvent;
     public void OnSomethingHappened
     {
         MyClassEvent?.Invoke(); // pass MyClass to subscribers
     }
}

public class AnotherClass(IMyInterface ...)
{
    OnMyClassEvent(MyClass args)
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us `MyClassEvent`, and your declaration of `AnotherClass` appears to have parameters, somehow... But yes, event types have to be delegates. Presumably `MyClass` is not a delegate type. Perhaps you want `EventHandler<MyClass>`?

Comment: It seems like you don't really understand how events work, please see examples of delegates and events on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare the event correctly and define the event args:

```
public class MyClassEventArgs : EventArgs { }

public interface IMyInterface
{
    event EventHandler<MyClassEventArgs> MyClassEvent;
}

public class Implementation : IMyInterface
{
    public event EventHandler<MyClassEventArgs> MyClassEvent;

    public void OnSomethingHappened()
    {
        MyClassEvent?.Invoke(this, new MyClassEventArgs());
    }
}
```

And to subscribe to it:

```
var implementation = new Implementation();
implementation.MyClassEvent += MyClassEvent;

private void MyClassEvent(object sender, MyClassEventArgs e) { ... }
```

Comment: Is EventHandler the new way to do it?  I've seen a lot of examples using delegate?

Comment: `EventHandler<T>` came along in .NET 2 and is the way to go, prior to that you had to declare your own delegate