# In Blazor, how can I create an interface with EventCallback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

In Blazor, the EventCallback struct is a bit different from standard events, being single-cast instead of multi-cast, etc. For that reason, I don't think this is a duplicate.

I am trying to create a set of components that all have the same [parameter] EventCallback, and it seems reasonable to use an interface to enforce that... So far this doesn't seem to be possible.

Things I've tried:

**Treating this like EventHandler**

```
public interface IResolver
{
    event EventCallback Done;
}
```

This raises the error: Event must be a delegate type.

...And other variations on trying to make this work like an EventHandler.

**Trying to use IEventCallback**

EventCallback implements IEventCallback, so this seemd promising. However, it is an internal interface,  and is not available to me.

**Using a base class instead**

This seems like it might work, but I am curious why I can't do this with an interface.

Also found:

- [Event must be of delegate type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33548781/event-must-be-of-delegate-type)
- Various articles about implementing event-like constructs using interfaces, or help with EventHandler, which is not the same thing.

None of that seems to be related to this problem.

Comment: I assume you don't need the multicast aspect, so why not declare the `EventCallback` as an ordinary property on the interface?

Comment: Have you tried declaring it like `public EventCallback MyCallBack { get; set; }` in your interface?

Comment: @ShaunCurtis No, I didn't try that because I don't normally declare EventCallbacks as properties - it does seem to work as far as the interface goes, though!  I would need to test more to see if everything works in the implementation. You feel like it will? I am not sure how these are implemented, but I do see a lot of notes that they are "special".

Comment: @BrianMacKay.  Yes it works, see my answer below. It has to be declared as a property to work with the component builder "factory" and the Renderer. Note the added `[Parameter]` in the implementation class.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis Great - I'm accepting this now, will test it a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: NP.  Get back if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the Callback using the correct syntax and it will work.

Here's my test code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TestBlazorServer
{
    public interface ICallbackComponent
    {
        public EventCallback MyCallBack { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
// TestCallback.razor
@namespace  TestBlazorServer

@implements ICallbackComponent
<h3>TestCallback</h3>

<button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="() => this.CallCallback()">Test Me</button>
```

We now declare `MyCallBack` with `[Parameter]`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TestBlazorServer
{
    public partial class TestCallback : ComponentBase, ICallbackComponent
    {
        [Parameter] public EventCallback MyCallBack { get; set; }

        private void CallCallback()
        {
            MyCallBack.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And we can declare multiple instances in `index.razor`.

```
// index.razor
<TestCallback MyCallBack="Callback1"></TestCallback>

<TestCallback MyCallBack="Callback2"></TestCallback>

<TestCallback MyCallBack="Callback3"></TestCallback>

<div>Test:@called</div>

@code {
    private string called;

    private void Callback1()
        => called = "First";

    private void Callback2()
        => called = "Second";

    private void Callback3()
        => called = "Third";
```